# How can I represent a message in sign computation for RSA?

Tags: string, encoding, cryptography, rsa

In my RSA algorithm implementation I should evaluate the following expression:

```
b = ((m-da)*H)mod(p-1)
```

While all the elements in the expression are integers, `m` is a String. That is a problem for me. How can I use a String in the case? Particularly I need that to sign the message `m`.

Comment: This doesn't look like RSA to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I use a String in the case?

You can't. `m` needs to be an integer. You need to devise some kind of encoding like convert to a byte array using some kind of character encoding like UTF-8. Then you can use some kind of encoding to unserialize the byte array into an integer. Have a look at how big-endian or little-endian type of integer encodings work.

Comment: But how in future will I be able to get my String back from the number `m`?

Comment: Reverse the process. An encoding always has a decoding function. Assuming that the math is correct and you can recover `m`, of course.

Comment: Could you please create a chat for us to discuss the RSA? I have some questions and I consider them inappropriate for being asked directly, but not in chat. And I have very little rate, so I ask you about creating the room.

Comment: Why not ask about it on [crypto.se]?